# Failure to run shutil.copytree when source folder on network drive

Tags: python, shutil

Half of our developers are running into an issue using shutil.copytree.
I think this is a Python question, but it could likely be a networking/hardware question as well, so I am providing as much information as possible, which may or my not be relevant.

Our company has developers spread across 2 locations, we are all on Windows 10, and using python 3.7.9.

Network drives are mimicked to be the same at both locations:

- We have a Y: drive, which is a mounted network drive. Each location cannot access the Y: drive from the other location.
- We have a `\\<domain_name>\code` DFS path that's another network path, where the code is "released" and served from, and synchronized between the 2 locations via DFS replication.

When developers have code to release, they run a release script, the whole release is staged on their Y: drive, then the whole package is copied over to the `\\<domain_name>\code` via a python `shutil.copytree`.

This works flawlessly at our Location A, but has a considerable failure rate in our LocationB, where the devs often encounter the following error (double backslashes edited for legibility):

`shutil.Error: [('Y:\package\src\file.py', '\\domain\code\package\src\file.py', "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Y:\package\src\file.py\file.py'")]`

We have occasionally encountered the same error when copying via shutil from `Y:` to `Y:`, though we rarely do this so 90% of the time the error occurs from Y: to DFS.

The folder structure we're trying to copy from might look something like this:

```
Y:\
    package\
        src\
            file.py
            file2.py
```

I did notice that in the error message: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Y:\package\src\file.py\file.py'`, it seems to indicate that it's looking for a file `file.py\file.py` which indeed does not exist, and was never meant to exist.

While this usually happens as part of our deployment script, it can be reproduced by running a copy manually:

```py
import shutil
src = r'Y:\package'
dst = r'\\domain\code\package'
shutil.copytree(src, dst)
```

I have dug into the shutil code, and the error it raises in copytree would be:
`(srcname, dstname, str(the_OSError))`, so somehow the `srcname` and `dstname` are correct, but somewhere the `srcname` changes like if it did `os.path.join(srcname, os.path.basename(srcname))`.

To make things more fun, the error never seems to occur if I have a debugger attached, so I'm having a hard time figuring out where exactly the issue is happening. I've been trying to follow the code and imagine where things could go wrong but I'm not finding it. Maybe some race condition disappears when the debugger makes lines run one by one.

Usually, everything would succeed on a retry, or if not on the next retry, which points me at maybe it's one of the os.path methods being called on Y: returning a lie because of some weirdness with the network drive, but even then I don't see where the shutil code would go wrong exactly.

Does anyone have any clue as to what it may be?

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: What protocol do your network shares use?

Comment: As an alternative to `copytree()`, what if you invoked an external program to do the copy? Something like `import subprocess; subprocess.check_call(['xcopy', '/E', src_dir, dest_dir])`

Comment: @Barmar I'm editing the post to add this information.

Comment: @NickODell I'm trying to find out more info about the protocol/specs of the network storage. Doing a subprocess might work, but copytree had the advantage of being OS agnostic, as a new office is being opened and they're running on Linux, but ideally would use the same deployment script. It's an option if we don't figure anything out though.

Comment: How often does this error occur? If you write a program which repeatedly runs copytree, deletes the dest folder, then repeats, and catches exceptions, how many times out of a hundred does this fail?

Comment: Any chances that the files in Y: was modified during the copy? For example, your developers are editing some of the files in those folders?

Comment: Many text editor would overwrite files by creating a new file in a temporary file and then renaming that into the destination. Over a network drive, this could've been interpreted as deleting the old file and then creating a new file. Momentarily, the files might actually not exist in the remote Y: drive.

Comment: Also, this feels like you're really asking the wrong question. You should be using a system that's actually designed for atomic distributed replication, rather than abusing a networked/distributed filesystem. For starter, your developers should be committing code to Git, and then releases would just be a matter of pulling the release branch from a Git repository rather than replication over network/distributed filesystem. On more advanced use cases, you should have an artefact repository like a private PyPI or a container repository where you store builds.

Comment: @NickODell the failure rate seems to vary depending on network usage. 30% when busy, 10 or less when not.

Comment: @LieRyan there is no chance the file in Y was modified. Also note how shutil comes up with a new path that never existed. As to your next comment regarding Git and such, we used Git extensively, as well as something akin to a private PyPi repository. In fact the script that fails is part of that system and it's failing trying to copy our build (staged on Y) to our shared repository which is on the DFS server. All signs point at something messed up on Y, but by posting here I hoped someone might be able to shed a light on how shutil makes up a new path.

Comment: `copytree()` internally calls `copy2()`, which can call `os.path.join()` with the original filename if the destination exists and is a directory. [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/shutil.py#L264) Maybe someone else is creating a directory with that filename, then immediately deleting it? Don't know if that's what's happening, but seems to match the symptoms. Maybe you could try the `copy_function=shutil.copyfile` argument to `copytree()`?

Comment: I suspected this path join but ignored it because the error seems to relate to the source rather than the destination. It's worth confirming though, I should be able to trigger this manually see if it results in the same error message, and will try to change the copy function too.